# Via VBA How to handle HTML Radio/drop-down buttons whose also effect other HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, vba

Respected Experts,I want to handle HTML Radio/drop-down buttons whose also effect other HTML elements.Please find the below HTML code.

[image]

```
appIE.document.getElementById("MainContent_DDLLevel1").selectedindex = 4
```

I am mange to handle 1st element via above code to select diff. options. Requesting you to kindly guide how can the other elements will be change automatically Via VBA. like in generally its change when user select the option's.

Comment: Are you using full VBA or VB Script?

Comment: @Anil Sir i am using Excel VBA

Comment: You can use .Item and .Value to select/set an option in select, e.g. .Document.forms("yourform").Item("MainContent_Chk1stLevel1").Value = "Chemical".

Comment: @Anil Sir Can you guide me with the help of the given HTML code how can I apply your above suggestion in my query.I am not that much good in VBA.